# undefined symbol for architecture x86_64 in compiling C program while using aerospike client library

Tags: c, linker-errors, aerospike

I am new to aerospike and just getting used to it. Now I have installed the C client library as they have described in their documentation.

Here is my code
[Test.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/env7G.png)

And this is the error that I get on compiling it.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn1fL.png)

I am assuming here that the linker is somehow not able to connect the function of the aerospike client to my code. I am not able to understand how to solve it!

Comment: Please paste your code in your question to help others to try it easily.

Comment: It would be better if you copy and pasted the text of your code and error here instead of screenshots.

Comment: You're using open source code. You can, and should contribute to it by opening a well written bug report: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/issues

Answer (score 1):

Here are my notes from using C Client inside an Ubuntu VM, Aerospike server is also installed inside this VM and running.

```
Using eclipse to develp C code:
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
Note: C Client does not support AsuRM processors.
I am working inside a Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

$lsb_release -a   ⇒ shows my ubuntu version 

pgupta@ubuntu:/var/log/aerospike$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:    xenial

Required library:

$cd ~
$sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Download C Client and install for Ubuntu 16.x:  http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/c/install

It was downloaded in my ~/Downloads directory.
$cd Downloads/
$ls
$tar xvf aerospike-client-c-4.1.1.ubuntu16.04.x86_64.tgz
$cd aerospike-client-c-4.1.1.ubuntu16.04.x86_64/
$ sudo dpkg -i aerospike-client-c-devel-4.1.1.ubuntu16.04.x86_64.deb
$ cd examples
$ make
$cd basic_examples/
$cd put
$cd target/
$ sudo service aerospike start   (I have a server running in my ubuntu 16 VM)
$./example

Output shows I was able to read and write records to the server.
```